# Http with token in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

(Sorry for my bad english) I have to access an api, with a token that they have provided me. My problem is that I don't know how to implement it, after searching and searching, it gives me the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.presupuestoabierto.gob.ar/api/v1/credito' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

**I pass my code to you, to indicate that it is wrong in the definition of the token (the x instead of the token) and eventually in the CORS policy, thank you very much!**

```
const headers = { 'Authorization': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8100'}
    this.http.get<any>('https://www.presupuestoabierto.gob.ar/api/v1/credito', { headers }).subscribe(data => {
      this.datos = data.blabla;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers should pass like this in Ionic- Angular. Make sure that you have a service file.Visit this link to know more about services:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

```
let headers = new Headers({
'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
'Auth':authvalue
});

return this.http.get(url,options).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
```